# Android Firebase cannot refresh email verification status

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my Android app, I am creating user and sending verification email. I want to proceed to the next page when the user has verified by clicking the link in the email received. However, the verification status didn't update so I cannot proceed. I have tried signing out and signing in again which works but I don't want to refresh the status in this way. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
public void onClickContinueBtn() {
   final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   user.reload().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
           if(task.isSuccessful()) {
               if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
                   // not verified block
                   // get into here even if verified
               } else {
                   // email verified, go to next page
               }
           } else {
               // do nothing, or show error
           }
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue and I dont think it is possible to refresh the email verification status in the current Firebase version without reauthenticating the user. The best solution i've found so far is using the **reauthenticate** method (in a dialog with email and password fields for example).
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. I'm using FirebaseUI and automatically it creates user on Firebase DB even if email has not yet been verified. But Firebase give you possibility to check if email has been verified or not by means of method `user.isEmailVerified`.Two possibilities:

1. If you want to guarantee access to your app only when email is verified: you could open a dialog when user signedIn and wait for verification. To cancel dialog automatically (only when email is verified) you can add an observer to that variable and so you can give access to your app.
2. If you give access to your app also without verification of email, you can check it with boolean isEmailVerified. Remember that you have to refresh current user with method reload() on FirebaseUser. Note that the update of that boolean is not instantaneous

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh the user by calling `reload` after every few seconds.
Example:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 5000; //milliseconds

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Toast.makeText(EmailVerificationActivity.this, "I'm here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);
```