# Email not being Verified in Firebase

Tags: android, email, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase's `isEmailVerified` method to verify an email. The following is the code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verifying);
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    spinner=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Log.e("I am launched","hello");
    if(user.isEmailVerified()==true){
       Log.e("I am here","hello");
        State state= new AccountSettingUp(this);
       state.doAction();
   } else {
        Log.e("Maybe i am here","yes");
       user.sendEmailVerification()
               .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                       if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                           Log.d("email", "Email sent.");
                       }
                   }
               });
   }
```

Here, the `else` code should only run when the email is not verified. However, even after I verify the email and restart the activity, the `if` statement is not `true` and the email is sent again.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior appears to be a limitation, possibly a bug, in the current version (10.0.1) of Firebase Authentication.  The same issue is reported in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40859227/4815718).

I tried doing a [reload()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#reload()) of the user data after the email verification.  That didn't help.  As reported in the related question, it seems that a sign-out/sign-in is required to get the new email verification status.

Answer (score 1):

For firebase-auth:10.0.1, it seems that it is not possible. However, the workaround is to log the user out and logging them in again. Upon signing in, the isEmailVerified() function will work properly.

I did a sign up activity

```
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileChange = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDisplayName(FirstName)
                                    .build();

                            user.updateProfile(profileChange).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Thanks for signing up, " + FirstName + "! Please verify your email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        user.sendEmailVerification();
                                        mAuth.signOut();
                                        Intent a = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Login_Activity.class);
                                        startActivity(a);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Failed to create username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

As seen in the 'task.isSuccessful()' portion of the '.updateProfile' code, I did an 'mAuth.signOut();' and informing them to verify their email before sending them back to the login screen.

On the Login screen, I did a simple 'if (user.isEmailVerified())' statement to check for verification. If they are still not verified, a toast will appear to remind them, if they are verified then they will proceed into the next activity.

Hope this helps!